# How to access dictionary value by key inside array of dictionary on Swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary, swift3

I've been away for a while from swift development. And today I got bug report from my client on my old project. The thing is I used to access value from my dictionary with ease just like **dictionary[key]** then I already got the value, but today I got below error by doing that:

> Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

and here is my code:

```
var rollStatusArray = NSMutableArray()

for statusDict in rollStatusArray{
  if statusId == "\(statusDict["mark_status_id"]!!)"{
    return "\(statusDict["mark_status_name"]!!)"
  }
}
```

How can I access dictionary value on swift 3?

Comment: What is the type of `rollStatusArray`?

Comment: @NiravD its an array of dictionaries

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra It will, can you show its declaration.

Comment: @NiravD I edited my question

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Thats the issue You are working with `NSMutableArray` show complier doesn't know the type of `statusDict` and that is the reason you are getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift's use native type `Array/[]` instead of `NS(Mutable)Array`.

```
if let dicArray = rollStatusArray.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]] {
    for statusDict in dicArray { 
        //Here compiler know type of statusDict is [String:Any]

        if let status_id = statusDict["mark_status_id"] as? String, status_id == statusId {
             return "\(statusDict["mark_status_name"]!)" 
        }
    }
}
```

Note I'm force wrapping the `mark_status_name` value you can use `Nil coalescing operator` to return empty string to remove force wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell compiler the type of your `statusDict` this way:

```
for statusDict in rollStatusArray {

    if let obj = statusDict as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let statusIdFromDict = obj["mark_status_id"] as? String ?? ""
        if statusId == statusIdFromDict {

            return statusIdFromDict
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 3, you can access the dictionary value the following way:

```
var rollStatusArray = NSMutableArray()
for statusDict in rollStatusArray{
    if statusId == "\((statusDict as! NSDictionary)["mark_status_id"]!)"{
            return "\((statusDict as! NSDictionary)["mark_status_name"]!)"
    }
}
```